# Controlling the transition animation in a page view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uipageviewcontroller

When using [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerClassReferenceClassRef/UIPageViewControllerClassReference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIPageViewController/setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:), can I programatically control the transition animation? I don't just want to trigger it and let it perform; I want to fine control it. That is, I want to say that the transition occurred to 20%, or 50%, etc. Like a gesture recognition, in which you drag forward and backwards and the animation follows, I want to simulate this movement, but using code.

The motivation for this is because I'm using a different view to control the transition. I can do this manually, but if the page controller already allows this, it would save me the trouble.

I read several material on this, but they all seem to use binary control (start and end).